# wildcard used in file name not recognized in batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, wildcard, filepath

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=* usebackq" %%u in ("\\%%a\C$\ProgramData\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\12.1.*\Data\Definitions\VirusDefs\definfo.dat) do (
```

I'm trying to read the second line of the file `definfo.dat`, using the below command through a batch file where `%%a` is the computer name. The wildcard is not recognized when I execute this. It looks for a folder with name *`12.1.*`* instead looking for any combination of *`12.1.1, 12.1.2, 12.1.3`* and so on.

What am I doing wrong here? Since the path also has a space, I'm unable to exclude the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You are only allowed to use wildcards in the last element of a path, so, your code with a wildcard in the middle will fail.

You need another `for` command to search for the folder

```
....
for /d %%z in (
    "\\%%a\C$\ProgramData\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\12.1.*"
) for /f "skip=1 tokens=* usebackq" %%u in (
    "%%~z\Data\Definitions\VirusDefs\definfo.dat"
) do (
....
```